# Arduino Nano PWM pin not functioning

Tags: pwm

I am building a project using an Arduino Nano. In it, I am using pin 3 as PWM output. However, If I supply values lower than 255 to it, the pin does not output any voltage at all.

According to this diagram, pin 3 is PWM:

[image: NANO pinout]

I have tested it on two boards, it doesn't function on either one. It's not my sketch, either (I tested it with a simple `analogWrite();`).

This is the code:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  #define E1 3  // Enable Pin for motor 1
  #define E2 10  // Enable Pin for motor 2
  #define I1 4  // Control pin 1 for motor 1
  #define I2 2  // Control pin 2 for motor 1
  #define I3 A1  // Control pin 1 for motor 2
  #define I4 A0  // Control pin 2 for motor 2
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  // I use differential steering, speed is important
  analogWrite(E1, 100); // Run in full speed
  analogWrite(E2, 100); // Run in full speed

  // always go forward
  digitalWrite(I1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(I2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(I3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(I4, HIGH);
}
```

What could be the reason of this?

Comment: Request this to be moved to the arduino stackexchange

Comment: @JorenVaes how do I do this?

Comment: No code shown. What in the world are we supposed to speculate about then?

Comment: @Bort sorry, added the code.

Comment: Try to replace #define E1 3 with #define E1 PD3 and see if that helps.

Comment: @Dampmaskin that worked! I do not know why, as i use pin 10 by simply declaring it as "10". Could you post this as an answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `#define E1 3` with `#define E1 PD3` and see if that helps.

The `PBx`, `PCx` and `PDx` designations are unambiguous, so using those are pretty much a safe bet.

Comment: This is absolutely wrong advice. Arduino functions take Arduino pin numbers. In this case it just happened to work because `PD3` is `#define`d as 3 and the Arduino pin number is also 3. Try using `PB2` instead of the Arduino pin number 10 if you don't believe me. They are not even unambiguous. Those designators are just defined as the bit numbers (e.g. `PB3` is also 3).

Answer (score 0):

The third pin (pin 3) is not a PWM pin, it is the `RESET` pin.

The PWM pins are 6, 8, 9, 12, 13 and 14 (for Arduino Nano).

See [this image](https://goo.gl/images/j5AMdv):

[image: Nano pinout]

Comment: Shortened URL redirects to https://images.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ifuturetech.org%2Fifuture%2Fuploads%2F2014%2F03%2FArduino-nano-Pinout.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ifuturetech.org%2Fproduct%2Farduino-nano-v3-0%2F&docid=domJNeoO6sP-cM&tbnid=jRej863j-6l5rM%3A&vet=1&w=642&h=377&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim so not much point to replacing it.

Comment: @Carolene according to the schematic given by the OP, pin 3 means digital pin 3 = PORTD 3.  The part of your answer "The PWM pins are 6, 8, 9, 12, 13 and 14 (for Arduino Nano)" is completely misleading.

Answer (score -1):

Replace digitalWrite with analogWrite(pin, value)

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this would work. Did you read the accepted answer above or the comments under the question?

Answer (score -1):

Use `pinMode(NNN, OUTPUT)` at `setup()`?

Comment: Hi Denis, and welcome to Stack Exchange! Whilst you may be correct, please expand upon your answer, because as it stands it would be more suited as a comment. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This is a good answer, the PIN MODE is missing.